# Highstock: specify x-axis datetime period

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to specify Highstock xAxis datetime period as it is shown on the picture below (made in a image editor)?

[image]

I need to show different line series for specified time period (for example, one week). And there may be cases when size of data period is less than size of the chart period (there are series that starts with a data loss). But Highstock chart is scaled so series starts from chart beginning and the chart has the size of, for example, half of a week, but I need to keep the period the same.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by `ordinal` option, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal). Disable this and set `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`. Demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/L3jqL0hw/

Code sample:

```
        xAxis: {
            ordinal: false,
            min: Date.UTC(2007, 0, 1),
            max: Date.UTC(2019, 0, 1)
        },
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I looked for!